# Mavericks Internet Sharing over Ethernet stopped working

Tags: network, macos, internet-sharing, ethernet

I'm on 10.9, and I had been using internet sharing successfully again for the first time since Lion. Today though, it just decided to stop working again.

Network layout:

```
Modem -ethernet-> Router -ethernet-> Mac Pro -ethernet-> MacBook Pro Retina
```

The internet works fine on the Mac Pro, but it is no longer forwarding the proper DHCP settings to the MacBook.

Previously, the MacBook would get the IP address of 192.168.2.12, and was able to surf the web fine. (Though it wasn't able to connect to any AirPlay/AirPrint devices while on the ethernet interface)

Sometime today, a setting got messed up, and I'm not sure how to fix it or what setting it is.

The MacBook now has a "Self-assigned" IP of 169.254.121.24, even though it is set to use DHCP. The ethernet port on the Mac Pro that the MacBook Pro is connected to is showing a "Self-assigned" IP of 169.254.36.53, even though it is set up to use DHCP as well.

The internet sharing options appear to be correct: share connection from Ethernet 1 to Ethernet 2.

But alas, for no apparent reason, I'm not getting internet access.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I got it to work again. I had to manually enter the correct DHCP, IPv4, and DNS settings on the MacBook Pro.

Here are the settings I used to get it to work in Network Preferences on the MacBook Pro:

[image: TCP/IP Tab]

[image: DNS Tab]

I had previously tried to do this manually, but I only tried the IP address stuff, I didn't think about entering in the DNS server until I read this article: http://forums.beyond.ca/showthread/t-216916.html

It's dumb that I have to do this manually now, and that I still am unable to see AirPlay/AirPort devices.

Comment: Yeah this is the only way I can get it to work as well. I have a problem with wifi. If I get the macbook to forget the network and rejoin, I get a proper IP address. However as soon as I try to go to any website, the IP becomes self signed again.

Comment: This fixes the symptoms but not the problem. The problem is your DHCP server or servers aren't handing out DHCP information any more. Your solution, while valid, solves the DHCP problem by not using DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

Very good reply, it solved my problem.

However, how do you find the address you need to use for the manual configuration of the WiFi client?

The way I found the one that works with my system was to start a Terminal window and type

```
ifconfig -a
```

then look for a "bridge" interface with a valid inet (IPv4) address. I then used another address from the same network (e.g. if the bridge has 192.168.3.1 you specify 192.168.3.12) and follow the instructions given above.

Answer (score 1):

Following the instruction [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23501205#23501205) everything went back to normal again:

> Backup these 2 files:
>
> /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist
> /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
>
> Then delete these 2 files and reboot

The reboot took quite a while for me though.

Comment: A simple reboot worked for me.

Comment: No need to "back up and delete" - just rename the files, such as putting a `.sav` at the end. By renaming, you make the original files vanish and put them in a form that can be used to recover as needed.