# Internet Sharing from Ethernet over Wifi results in self-assigned IP address

Tags: network, wifi, internet, internet-sharing

I have OS X Mavericks with a Thunderbolt Ethernet connected to the internet with IP `192.168.0.1` (which is a subrouter of `192.168.1.1`).

I set up internet sharing through the Sharing interface and I am able to connect to the network and see it from my iPhone 5. My iPhone 5 is assigned an IP address in `192.168.2.*`, but it can't connect to the internet. On my Mac, the Wi-Fi interface shows a self assigned IP address.

I tried manually setting the WiFi to `192.168.2.12, 255.255.255.0, 192.168.2.1` with DNS `192.168.1.1, 192.168.0.1` as per ([Mavericks Internet Sharing over Ethernet stopped working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113057/mavericks-internet-sharing-over-ethernet-stopped-working)), but I haven't had any success. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Show us what your sys pref sharing screen look like.

Comment: This? http://i.gyazo.com/8c87f79120532c7291615c808ced0d2d.png http://i.gyazo.com/525aecb4510df7f766c1823c2c58e99a.png